# Kile does not show compile action

Tags: kile

A problem rather with Kile than with Tex -- how can I compile?
The options are greyed out and I could not find out how to change that. 
Live preview works fine.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I restarted Kile (without having done any changes to the configuration or system) and now the option is there. Wow.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me.  No options in the Compile menu.  Restart Kile and they're all there.